# Locally exact form $P\;dx+Q\;dy$ , and the property $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a very known result, but I don't have some proof. Someone known or has some proof of it?

> Let be $\omega  = P\;dx + Q\;dy$ be a $C^1$ differential form on a domain $D$. If $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} ,$$ then $\omega$ is locally exact.

Comment: This is the [Poincaré-lemma in its most basic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_lemma#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma). Since this is closely related to your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87577/closed-forms-and-a-simple-relation-with-cauchy-riemann) I strongly recommend that you do some reading on [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) and the wedge product (written $\wedge$)

Comment: Cartan's book *Elementary theory of analytic functions ...* gives [a very readable answer](http://books.google.com/books?id=KsGbqTBjyoUC&pg=PA49) to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a curl-free field $W = (W_1, W_2, W_3)$ in a neighborhood of the origin, it is the gradient of a function $f$ given by
$$ f(x,y,z) =   \int_0^1 \; \left( \;  x W_1(tx, ty,tz) +  y W_2(tx, ty,tz) + z W_3(tx, ty,tz)  \; \right)  dt.$$

In your case, take $W_3 = 0$ and drop the dependence on $z$ from $f, \; W_1$ and $W_2.$ Note how this is set up so that $f=0$ at the origin.

There is more information at [Anti-curl operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator/81477#81477)